# Files View, How to display Images related to Media Gallery?

Tags: views, media

I have created a view in views to show files of type image. Under fields I have selected File Rendered. Now my view is displaying all the images.

The problem is this that **I only want to display images which belongs to galleries created through media gallery module**.

Answer (score 0):

In my view under relationships I used **File: Content using Gallery media**. This is now showing the images which are related media Media Gallery.